# Slow response from asp.net web api

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, iis-express

I'm wondering if anyone has any as to why a response from a web api can be slow from the second it is requested to when it is returned.

I thought it was the code within the action in the controller so I commented it out and I'm just returning ok but:

1. When called from `Postman`, it still takes 2.05 secs (avg)
2. When called from `IE`, it still takes 1.95 secs (avg)

I thought it was because I was running in `IIS Express` but when deployed to IIS on another server, I'm getting very similar results.

I've just tested the request time from another project (personal one) and to request and response and send back 1Mb of data, it take 0.47ms on average.

Requests are made over http on my localhost.

Any ideas what could be slowing it down like that? I don't understand how just returning Ok can take 2 seconds from the request to the response??

**Update-1**

Here are some additional details as requested:

- GET request
- Total time: 2.19s
- Size: 2.6kb
- Queuing: 1.56ms
- Stalled: 1.27ms
- Request Sent: 0.38ms
- Waiting (TTFB): 2.18s
- Content Download: 1.14ms

Comment: You say average times, so I am assuming you are making requests one after the other and not giving any app pool a chance to stop?

Comment: @CraigH No, I've just called the specific url from Postman or IE multiple times and observed the time taken for each request made. So taking Postman for example, it was something like 2.08, 2.05, 2.11, 2.03 etc... and IE was something like 1.95, 1.90, 1.98. Remember that the action in my controller was changed to do absolutely nothing except return OK as the StatusCode so it should be super fast but somehow it isn't.

Comment: At least it seems consistent... Have you added anything into the pipeline (like authentication filters) which get executed on every request? Or custom attributes on the controller/ method which are running? Perhaps something like that is doing a really slow database lookup?

Comment: When on the same machine one application is fast and the other is slow, you need to identify the differences. We can't do that for you, as you haven't shared any specifics on either project.

Comment: Do you have any code part in the constructor of your controller (e.g. DB call) which can be slow? A new controller instance is created on every request.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? One of my asp.net apps is slow every request. 8-10 sec request. chrome dev tools sees this 8-10sec in TTFB. Server's IIS logs also show request taking 8-10sec. IIS worker process monitor shows the request taking that long too so it leads me to believe that the slowness is in the asp.net pipeline. Logging code in my controller is always under 2 sec so something else in the pipeline is slowing things down?

Comment: @gilm0079 yeah we did. It had to do with dependency injection. I can't recall exactly and unfortunately I don't have access to the code since I no longer work in the company, but in short, it was triggering an event every single time for each services instead of just once when the web api was initialized which meant the more requests were coming through, the more events were being re-initialized every time which caused the slow down over time. It took forever to spot tbh! I'll check with my colleague as he may have better re-collection since he discovered the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you compared the timeline of event in F12 developer tool network tab.First of all, we need to know which process is slower than your personal project. Stalled?sending? Waiting(TTFB)?or downloading?

If the request is slow in TTFB, you could try to set FRT rule to capture failed request tracing performance log and compare which module is causing the slow performance.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/2008/08/19/troubleshooting-a-performance-issue-with-failed-request-tracing-and-appcmd-in-iis7/

Comment: I used the developer tools to give me the time taken by the request when used in IE. As for the process, I'm not sure what you mean? Both my work and personal project as both ASP.NET Web API and to carry out test as to why my work project was so slow, I commented all the code in one of my actions in the relevant controller and just returned OK as the response, thus eliminating my service logic being the culprit. In any case, the service logic only took around 400 ms which is still far out from 2 seconds.

Comment: The action I'm taking is a standard GET request and there's nothing special about it. I will read the link you provide and see if it helps.

Comment: I mean this. https://i.ibb.co/7Xv2vCT/slow1.png. we need to know application is slower in downloading or waiting response from server. If the low performance come from server side. Then we start from Failed request tracing to figure out whether this low performance is caused by asp.net module

Comment: I've updated the answer as requested. I will try the same thing with a get request that does absolutely nothing and just returns ok as done in my original test and it took just as long.

Comment: It seems that IIS server spend about 2 second to handle the request. I think you could enable failed request tracing to log the request  over 2seconds. Then we would know which module is impacting the performance. If the low performance issue is caused by asp.net pipeline. Then you may require to capture performance dump with debug diagnostic and do professional dump analysis with WINDBG or debug diagnostic tool analysis. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/docast/2016/04/28/troubleshooting-iis-request-performance-slowness-issues-using-freb-tracing/

Comment: I'll update you as soon I have something but this has now been put as a low priority and I have to concentrate on other parts of the project I'm working on, not to mention that we don't have control over IIS and we'll have to put a request in with IT so that will take some time too :(

Comment: No problem. Since the request only spend 2seconds to finish the request. It would probably a bit hard to capture two continuous dump for the same request. You could try to generate dump file every 1 second .